# How to update header value when user login - blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working with a Blazor web assembly application and facing an issue. I want to update the username and profile image on the top menu when a user logs in.

So, the approach I used is, when a user logs in, store username and profile image URL in the local storage. And fetch that from the header component.

Header.razor

```
<span>@_username</span>                                    
<img src="@_profileImageUrl" alt="">

@code{
    string? _username;
    string? _profileImageUrl;

    public async Task GetUserInfo()
    {
        _username = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("username");
        _profileImageUrl = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("profileImageUrl");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

Login.razor

```
<Header @ref="_header"></Header>

@code{
    
    private Header _header { get; set; }
        
    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        var loginResponse = await AuthenticationService.Login(_model);
        if (loginResponse.Success)
        {
            await _header.GetUserInfo();
            var returnUrl = NavigationManager.QueryString("returnUrl") ?? "/myaccount";
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {            
            NotificationService.Notify(Notification.Error(loginResponse.Message));
        }
    }    
}
```

App structure

```
-Controls
 -Header.razor
-Pages
 -Login.razor
```

Local storage is getting updated on login success. But the header values aren't updated.

I have tried to cascade the values from the main layout page; it works partially. When I hard refresh the page, both the values become null.

**Edit-1:**

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
        public async Task<Response<AuthenticationResponse>> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            var loginResponse = await _httpService.Post<AuthenticationResponse>("api/auth/login", loginViewModel);
            if (loginResponse.Success)
            {
                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("authToken", loginResponse.Data.AccessToken);
                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("refreshToken", loginResponse.Data.RefreshToken);
                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("username", loginResponse.Data.FirstName);
                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("profileImageUrl", loginResponse.Data.ProfileImageUrl);

                ((AuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyUserAuthentication(loginResponse.Data.AccessToken);
            }

            return loginResponse;
        }
}
```

**Edit-2** 
MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<RadzenNotification />
<div class="page">
    <main>
        <Header></Header>
        <div>
            @Body
        </div>
        <Footer></Footer>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where local storage is populated and the code that calls HandleLogin?  My guess is that something is not being 'awaited' somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  I note that after asking the sub-component (Header.razor) of Login.razor to `GetUserInfo()` you immediately navigate away.  So, any updates to that instance of Header.razor will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this kind of feature in a header would be to put the header in a layout component.

Additionally, create a small service like so:

```
public class UserStatusService
{
    public event EventHandler UserLoggedIn;

    public void UserIsLoggedIn()
    {
        UserLoggedIn?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Register this in your services, and inject it into Login.razor.

Then, from login.razor, after successful login call:

```
_userStatusService.UserIsLoggedIn();
```

In header component:

```
@inject UserStatusService _userStatusService
@implements IDisposable

@code {
    string? _username;
    string? _profileImageUrl;

    protected override OnInitialized()
    {
        _userStatusService.UserLoggedIn += HandleLoggedIn;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _userStatusService.UserLoggedIn -= HandleLoggedIn;
    }

    void HandleLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _username = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("username");
        _profileImageUrl = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("profileImageUrl");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! *The simplest way to implement this kind of feature in a header would be to put the header in a layout component.* The header control is in `MainLayout.razor` page only, updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edits to the answer.  Hopefully, your problem is now solved.  PS.  Your question still shows an instance of Header component included as a sub-component of Login.razor.  Note that this means any activity in the `instance` on Login.razor will not reflect in the instance in the layout component.

Comment: Yes, I understood, and implemented the way you suggested. It's working fine. Thanks a lot!  P.S. I don't want to modify actual question, otherwise the actual context might change.

Comment: Would be great if you can help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74135273/4753489