# How to handle authentication in blazor application with prerendering enabled

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly, pre-rendering

I trying to implement token base authentication in Blazor webassembly web application with **Prerendering enabled**.

The steps I have done so far:

1. Created a sample Blazor Webassembly application
2. Followed the Official MS doc: [Prerender and integrate ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly)
3. Checked if application works
4. Added token base authentication (custom) changes - [ref.](https://code-maze.com/blazor-webassembly-authentication-aspnetcore-identity/)

It gives an error at `AuthStateProvider`

```
public class AuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {       
        var token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            return _anonymous;

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(JwtParser.ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwtAuthType")));
        
        return _anonymous;
    }
}
```

It gives an error

> InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued
> during server-side prerendering, because the page has not yet loaded
> in the browser. Prerendered components must wrap any JavaScript
> interop calls in conditional logic to ensure those interop calls are
> not attempted during prerendering.

at this line

```
var token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
```

Now that is obvious; this line should be wrapped in a condition to check for prerendering like:

```
public class AuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {   
        var isNotPreRendering = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted;    
        
        if(isNotPreRendering)
        {
            var token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                return _anonymous;
    
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
    
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(JwtParser.ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwtAuthType")));
        }
        
        return _anonymous;
    }
}
```

But the value of `isNotPreRendering` always false. Is there any other way or work around to make it work?

Comment: `IHttpContextAccessor` should not be used with Blazor. I suggest you read about this matter. [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22820), [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Thanks, yeah I need to know about other alternative way to check whether application is in prerender mode or not

Comment: I think this is more the context in which you are calling this than checking for prerendering. You should do it in `OnAfterRenderAsync()` for example.

Comment: I have seen this solution to use `OnAfterRenderAsync()` but not sure how to do it

Comment: Where is `AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync` called ?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine It's override method, it will check on every request I guess

Comment: @DivyangDesai an example to implement onAfterRender that i use ->  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        { 
                await js.InvokeVoidAsync("changeSvgViewbox", "");
            
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

Comment: @LeandroToloza But the question is, where to add it?

Comment: @DivyangDesai on your Page.razor.cs

Comment: @LeandroToloza: sorry, I meant *on which page?*

Comment: Hello @DivyangDesai , I am running into the exact same problem, did you happen to fix it? How did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue in this way:

1. Once the app hits **GetAuthenticationStateAsync()** will find a try-catch, withing the catch I will return an AnonymousState.

   ```
        AuthenticationState anonymousState = new(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));

        try
        {
            var token = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
            var memberId = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<int>("memberId");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) || memberId == 0)
                return anonymousState;

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

            var authState = new AuthenticationState(
                new ClaimsPrincipal(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(JwtParser.ParseClaimFromJwt(token), "jwtAuthType")));

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(authState));

            return authState;
        }
        catch
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(anonymousState);
        }
   ```
2. In my MainLayout.cs I call the **AuthenticationState** again. This is not the cleanest solution but it does the work

Comment: Yes, I've used the same work-around. Another issue with this...the user information getting load lately after application rendered. So, not a good user experience.